# youtube video size in markdown

Tags: video, youtube, markdown

I'm trying to set size/dimension to the markdown youtube video

```
![](https://youtu.be/zNzZ1PfUDNk){width="90%"} 
![](https://youtu.be/zNzZ1PfUDNk){width="500" height="200"}
```

but it diesn't work. Maybe there are some other ways(through the url etc)?I need to set size exactly in markdown

Comment: Markdown doesn't support video embeds using image syntax, and it doesn't support injection of attributes using curly braces. But some tools add support for nonstandard stuff. What Markdown tool are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Markdown does not support video embed by default, but you can use images to link YouTube video.

```
[![Black Widow](https://img.youtube.com/vi/Fp9pNPdNwjI/default.jpg)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fp9pNPdNwjI)
```

`Fp9pNPdNwjI` is the unique address of the video and you can check the YouTube video link.
[image]

And there are some **size options**.

#### `/default`, `/1`, `/2`, `/3`

[image: Black Widow]
[image: Black Widow]
[image: Black Widow]
[image: Black Widow]

#### `/mqdefault`

[image: Black Widow]

#### `/hqdefault`

[image: Black Widow]

#### `/sddefault`

[image: Black Widow]

#### `/maxresdefault`

[image: Black Widow]

---

You can also specify the start point of the video when the image is clicked.
Just add `?t=` followed by The unique code of the video link.

#### `second`

```
[![Black Widow](https://img.youtube.com/vi/Fp9pNPdNwjI/mqdefault.jpg)](https://youtu.be/Fp9pNPdNwjI?t=29)
```

[image: Black Widow]

#### `minute&second`

```
[![Black Widow](https://img.youtube.com/vi/Fp9pNPdNwjI/mqdefault.jpg)](https://youtu.be/Fp9pNPdNwjI?t=1m24s)
```

[image: Black Widow]

#### `hour&minute&second`

```
[![The Greatest Showman](https://img.youtube.com/vi/gQa8bAtZkiY/mqdefault.jpg)](https://youtu.be/gQa8bAtZkiY?t=1h5m10s)
```

[image: The Greatest Showman]